Github Action Deployment of Azure Function Without Public Access from All Networks
A question about Github Action Deploying Azure Function which is in VNet
I have:

GitHub Repo + Action for deployment with Publish Profile
Azure Function that is a part of the VNet/Subnet/NSG

--
Works: I am able to deploy the function only if I enable full public access for the function.
Need: I would like to restrict that so that I would not need to have public access for the deployment.
Problem: I am not able to allow Github Action on IP/Service whitelist or VNet
--
I do not really want a function to be publicly available all the time. Switching public access on and off for the deployment does not feel right.
Any suggestions?

Hey Tridy, does this fail during the deploy step at the login.  I managed to deploy my (private) Function App by setting up the OIDC in the AzLogin step (where it failed).  To do this you need to find the "Application" used in EntraID, then under the app's Secret Keys, there will be a tab to add an additional OIDC.   You will need the environment string when setting this up, which I got from the error message in the GitHub failed workflow step output. (fyi. I used the Azure portal to setup the initial workflow in GitHub, and that was the missing piece for that).

In my case, the function's deployment profile solves the problem with login, and I can deploy if I keep "All networks public network access" for the function. However, I want only APIM (for actual access) and GitHub (for deployment) to be able to access the function, not full public access.
As for setting up the initial workflow in Azure Portal, we have the SSO enabled on the GitHub level, and the company does not come up in the drop-down in the portal for GitHub deployment, but I will research how to make it possible with SSO as well. Nor sure if it helps with network settings though.

Azure Portal installed the workflow file into GitHub for me when it was configured as the deployment source on the Func App resource in Azure.  When I made the Func App private, it complained about no OIDC and somehow I luckily came across something that mentioned about configuring the EntraID App.  I did a search for Github in the Applications and found one.  A recent MS update has split the Applications setting page, where one doesn't have the Secrets and Certs section... little fyi incase you can't find the setting page.

@tridy, Have you enabled the access restrictions in the storage account as well?

@PravallikaKV I see that access to the storage where the function hosts the code could be the problem. I do not think this is causing it though, since giving public access to the function allows proper deployment. I looked at the error logs and this is what I have found:
Failed to acquire app settings from https:///api/settings with publish-profile. Error: Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings. Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)

After some writing back and forth with MS Azure Support we have got the answer:

the ASP density is unhealthy so once the HealthCheck has to check it
privately as opposed to publicly it's also able to see the state of
the instances' minor problems and display them. Overall the ASP
density isn't something that would affect the health of an app unless
there's a lot of heavy apps running on it. That's why I recommended
splitting the 12 apps that are on the original ASP and moving half
under the new ASP which should help mitigate the occurrence you're
seeing.
As you're running an ASP with small instances the maximum recommended
apps to run on it is 8 in order to keep a healthy environment and it
doubles with every instance size (16 for Medium and 32 for Large).

We are running 12 rather small Azure Function on the Flexible Premium Function service plan. Everything works as expected, it is only the health-checks that freak out because of the larger number of functions. I do not see us purchasing an additional ASP only to fix this issue, so we will be implementing our own health-check routine instead. Maybe we will merge some of the functions into 1 later on.


Error: Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings. Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)

To resolve this error, add the below application settings in the Function app=>Settings=>Environment Variables:
WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1
WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET=1


I have enabled access restrictions in the function app by selecting Enabled from selected virtual networks and ip addresses and add a rule to enable VNET access:

Able to deploy the function to Azure function app with access restrictions using GitHub actions:

Portal:


I created a separate Function, and added it to the same VNet/Subnet/NSG and in this new one, I can deploy from GitHub without any issues or additional settings. I cannot test the deployment on the original function from the same environment but it looks to me that 2 functions with the same settings behave differently. I will check the deployment for the original function withing a couple of days and get back with the results.

by the way, it looks like AzureFunction HealthCheck is refusing to work as well, and reports "Health Check : 0.00% (Healthy 0 / Degraded 3)". As soon as I turn the public access on, the Health Check starts working. WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1 and WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET=1 does not help.

Try adding the setting WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER=168.63.129.16 as well.

WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER=168.63.129.16 did not help

I went back and recreated the function by starting from the beginning with Public network access: Disabled and added the function to VNet/Subnet/NSG with the default (no changes) inbound and outbound rules. With these settings, the deployment would fail as it was mentioned in the original posting. That did not publish regardless of whether the CI/CD was set up from the function as the first step or getting the publish profile and doing everything from GitHub side. Note that since there was VNet integration, it was still possible to communicate with the Fuction from withing the VNet, but again, deployments were not possible.
As soon as I switched to Public network access: Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses, without any changes to Site access and rules, the deployment went through. It still had the VNet/Subnet/NSG from earlier but now the deployment went through.
My findings:

Public network access: Disabled - blocks deployments
Public network access: Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses -
allows deployments.



The question that I have now myself is since there are no exceptions on the Rules level, how does GitHub get access to the Function? Are there any "hidden" rules that allow that?

On a side note, the problem with the health check still persists on the flexible function plan and it looks like Azure monitor and Azure backend see the functions as "Healthy" but the Portal states "Unhealthy", so we got tired of that and disabled the HealthCheck functionality on 10+ functions that we have in this ASP. Maybe we will look into this later but for now, we just got tired of trying to figure out what's wrong.
